# Android builds are supported only on Linux and macOS (React Native Expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, admob

Good morning everyone, I have an application made in Expo, and this week I was going to configure Admob to be able to upload it to the Playstore, but I was surprised by the discontinuity of Admob, requiring a whole new configuration, following the steps below for a simple test in a new blank app I'm not able to create the file to emulate and be able to follow the tests, could you check what I did wrong?

In the "Windows10" terminal:

1 - expo init test

2 - I go to the test folder

3 - expo install expo-dev-client

4 - expo install react-native-google-mobile-ads

Then I put this information in App.js inside Visual Studio code

"react-native-google-mobile-ads":{
"android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713",
"ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511"
}

test-only ids

In the terminal again

5 - npm install -g eas-cli
6 - easy login
7 - eas build:configure ( Here I select Android )

In this step, a new file appears in the folder, the eas.json, doing the 2 ways below it gives an error:

"android":{
"simulator":true
}

and even without adding anything

at the terminal

8 - eas build -p android --profile development --local

Now that there is a problem, it keeps giving the error below

"Android builds are supported only on Linux and macOS",

I use Windows 10, can I solve this somehow?

this is the video of the developer who did the above methods, in her case he did it via MAC, but I only have Windows 10, can I solve this somehow? what is my best option?

Thank you all in advance and sorry for the English, I'm Brazilian and I'm using Google translator.

Comment: If it literally says "Android builds are supported only on Linux and macOS", then it wont work. You could install WSL, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install and then build the app from a linux command line within windows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me!

- I installed Ubuntu on wsl on my windows machine
- Installed node and npm
- Used ubuntu to create the build file

Comment: I did as you said, but it still gives the same problem, I'll research a little more, the admob changed very recently, especially in Expo, I'll keep trying and see how it goes, thanks anyway, "eas build -p android --profile development --local" however when I remove the "--local", it goes to the web, I download it and I can work without errors (until then kkkkk ), I will continue and see if everything is really ok, for now, thank you very much

Comment: @how to create build file using ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this, but this might be a longer route

`eas build --profile development --platform android`

This uses the EAS server to build the APK. So you still have to download it and install on your device

Answer (score -1):

yes, just open Ubuntu in your project directory and execute step

```
EAS build -p android --profile development --local
```

then drop the generated APK file on your emulator or android and then switch back to PowerShell and execute step 9

Comment: Make command like a code (use 4 spaces at line starts)